# html and body's height is not 100%

Tags: php, html, css

[image]

I've tried everything I know to make the height of the black part change according to the "samples" in the picture above. Whenever I add new "sample" that will go down the black part does not follow. Is there something wrong in my code, if there is please let understand how to fix it cause Im new at this.

Here is my code:

```css
body,
html,
.yourteachers,
.fullpage
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.fullpage
{
  background-color: black;
}

.leftForm
{
  background-color: #2c384a;
  width: 204px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  font-family: calibri;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.yourteachers
{
  text-align: center;
}

.announcementSlider
{
  background-color: #323f4f;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 280px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/teachers.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper blue">
        <div class="container">
          <a href="#" class="brand-logo left">Teachers</a>
          <a href="#" class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="slide_out"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
          <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down right">
            <li><a id="dashb">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="logout">Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="fullpage">
    <div class="leftForm hide-on-med-and-down">
      <img src="pictures/default-avatar-250x250.png">
      <p class="name">
        <?php echo $name; ?>
      </p>
      <p class="section">
        <?php echo $grade; ?>-
        <?php echo $section; ?>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="leftForm sidenav blue center" id="slide_out">
      <img src="pictures/default-avatar-250x250.png">
      <p class="name">
        <?php echo $name; ?>
      </p>
      <p class="section">
        <?php echo $grade; ?>-
        <?php echo $section; ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="yourteachers">
      <?php
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo '<a class="announcementSlider" href="teacherinfo.php?id=' . $row['IDNum'] . '">
                    <img src="pictures/blank photo.png" class="teacherpic"><br>
                    <span>'.$row['LastName'].'</span><br>
                    <span>'.$row['Grade'].' - </span>
                    <span>'.$row['Section'].'</span>
                  </a>';
          }
        ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("announcementSlider");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      a[i].onclick = function() {
        location.href = "teacherinfo.php";
      };
    }
  </script>
  <script src="js/teachers.js"></script>
  <script src="sameFunctions.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const slide_menu = document.querySelectorAll(".sidenav");
    M.Sidenav.init(slide_menu, {});
  </script>

  <footer>
    <div class="foot">
      <div class="socialMed">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SchoolOfFelixians/" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is your html code?

Comment: already added it.

Comment: @bahman parsamanesh what did you edit?

Comment: I've added `html` tag

Comment: @PlusUltra You can click the link that says "edited X mins ago" to see revision history.

Comment: @csmckelvey already did that but I did not saw what he edited because im looking for changes in the code. sorry its my fault thanks for the info

Comment: Make sure you are doing a hard reload when making changes so your browser is using the newest CSS not a cached verison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `.fullpage` needs to follow `.yourteachers` 's height. And your `.leftForm` has `float: left` but it's parent (.fullpage) still doesn't know the exact height of it's children. To fix it, you need to add clear: both by using div with additional `.clearboth` class or css :before or :after pseudo-selector.

[see my fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5fg6och0/)

In my approach above, I'm using fixed sidebar and add margin-left on `.yourteachers` to fix sidebar height issue. For better implementation, I recommend you to use flex box so you keep your sidebar not using fixed position.

Comment: it works but i don't want to fixed the leftform. is there no other way to fixed this issue?

Comment: Here's solution with flex box with no fixed sidebar :
[flex box solution](https://jsfiddle.net/fo8s3v57/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- language-all: lang-css -->

body, html, .yourteachers, .fullpage {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
}
.fullpage {
    overflow: hidden
}
.leftForm{
    background-color: #2c384a;
    width: 204px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    font-family: calibri;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.yourteachers{
    text-align: center;
}

.announcementSlider{
    background-color: #323f4f;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 280px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You should describe what you did and why it solves the problem instead of just posting code.

Comment: @csmckelvey yes, I agree
I'm new here and I still try to figure out how to use Stackoverflow, once I can combine simple text with code - I'll do better

Answer (score -1):

Have u tried `height: 100vh`? Height is automatically adjusting, so just `height: 100%` means 100% height of parent.

Comment: yup. also nothing happened